# Excluding ".exe" in Windows Run opens Windows Explorer

Tags: windows

Why can I not always leave out `.exe` when running a program from the Run tool?

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `notepad` works

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `putty.exe` works

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `putty` doesn't work (opens Windows Explorer to the PuTTY location)

In command prompt, `putty` works. I have the PATH variable set up.

Comment: "`putty` doesn't work"  Doesn't work in what way?  What happens when you try?  Do you get an error?

Comment: It comes down to is the path to the executable int he Path variable.  Notepad works because the path to its executable exists in the variable by default.  Putty works in a command prompt because your likely in the folder, the executable exists in, but you were not specific enough to say with certainty.

Comment: I edited my question to address your comments.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a "putty" batch file, and that's what Run is running first when you don't specify the extension (probably due to Path entries as Ramhound mentions).  If you Win+R and then run `putty.bat` what happens?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 "Windows cannot find 'putty.bat'..."

Comment: Weird, perhaps try `Putty.cmd`? (CMD and Batch files are essentially the same thing).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 no go, double O :)

Comment: Well that's pretty whacked.  It's obviously running SOMETHING that changes you to that folder, as just running Putty.exe wouldn't do that. Here's another something to try, run `putty` and have it open that command window. Then open Task Manager, click the Processes tab, click View -> Select columns..., then enable "Command Line".   Head back to the Processes list, find the cmd.exe associated to that command window opened by `putty`, and then scroll over and read the "Command Line" column you just added.  What does it say?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish I'm not sure what you mean -- "Run"ing `system32` (etc.) does not open the System32 folder...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have two competing executable files with the name "putty" in the system path.  Check your system & user environments' `PATH` variables by following this [guide](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_environmnt_addchange_variable.mspx?mfr=true) - Chances are the resolution of the word "putty" is ambiguous.  `PATH` is searched in order, so you can move the value that resolves to the location of `putty.exe` earlier in the `PATH` and it will be found first.

Comment: Thanks Mekki! I had the WinSCP installation in my PATH variable which contains a folder for "PuTTY". I moved the WinSCP entry to the end as you suggested and that fixed it.